# Using Gazebo Plugin with .h File Type

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried compiling a Gazebo plugin that is a header file (with .h file extension), it says:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene".
```

The following is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${GAZEBO_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_library(gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene SHARED gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.h)
target_link_libraries(gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES})
```

Any suggestions for a fix? P.s. I'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.h#L50-L82

Edit: This is a cross-post of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/moveit-users/C5r9Liqh6rU/qezMdDjoAgAJ, http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18783/using-gazebo-plugin-with-h-file-type/, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288356/using-gazebo-plugin-with-h-file-type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285461/using-gazebo-plugin-with-.h-file-type/) by [stans](https://answers.ros.org/users/34130/stans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot compile a header file.

But you also don't need to: [jhu-lcsr-forks/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.cpp](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/fb2dbfb2c05d37b4fbc9b0007317c58a83c4751f/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.cpp).

Note that this plugin is only present in the `hydro-devel` branches, so might not be compatible with Indigo or later releases of Gazebo.

---

Edit: any reason you're using that fork specifically? If not, then that plugin is also hosted in the `hydro-devel` branch of upstream (ie: `gazebo_ros_pkgs`): [ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_moveit_planning_scene.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
And this is a cross-post of [How to use gazebo world file objects for planning with Moveit](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/moveit-users/C5r9Liqh6rU/qezMdDjoAgAJ) on `moveit-users`. If you *must* do this, then please mention that in your post.

**Comment by [stans](https://answers.ros.org/users/34130/stans/) on 2018-03-15**:
Thanks gvdhoorn! I apologize for the cross-post omission; I was not aware of the need to do so. I have made the necessary edit.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
re: cross-posts: there are no rules about this, other than netiquette. Cross-posts lead to duplication and waste of effort and split discussions. It's just not a very nice thing to do in online communities.